# Hierarquical clustering with big vector

Tags: matlab, bigdata, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm working in MATLAB and I have a vector of 4 million values. I've tried to use the `linkage` function but I get this error:

> Error using linkage (line 240) Requested 1x12072863584470 (40017.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

I've found that some people avoid this error using the `kmeans` functions however I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this error and still use the `linkage` function.

Comment: You need more RAM! like 40Tb of it, if you want to use the fucntion.

Comment: is there any other similar function that doesn't require that much memory?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  To answer that question you should include a minimal example of your problem in Matlab code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: to do what? linkage returns a matrix, and that matrix is that much memory, regarthless of who makes it. But you only mentioned that you want thta function, not what you are triying to do!

Comment: you're absolutely right. I'm trying to do hierarchical clustering with this values.

Comment: Its a hard problem. Hope you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most hierarchical clustering *needs* O(n²) memory. So no, you don't want to use these algorithms.

There are some exceptions, such as SLINK and CLINK. These can be implemented with just linear memory. I just don't know if Matlab has any good implementations.

Or you use kmeans or DBSCAN, which also need only linear memory.

Answer (score -2):

Are you absolutely sure that these `4 million values` are `statistically correct`? If yes, your a lucky person and if no, then do the `data pre-processing`. You'll see the 4 million values have drastically decreased to a meaningful sample which can easily be fit into the memory (RAM) to do hierarchical clustering.